# ReactJS Django admin page not found

Tags: python, reactjs, django, npm-build

I have a project with react and Django and after I ran the command

```
npm run build
```

and changed the Django static field settings to:

```
   'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build')],
```

I can't access the Django administration "http://localhost:8000/admin/" after I built up the project.

Comment: `npm` is for `React`, not for `Django`. What error do you get?

Comment: yes I no I am using django reset framework with react but when I run django with react in the same port after running " npm run build " I can't access to django admin page because react router will be excuted when I go to the link : http://localhost:8000/admin/"

Comment: React and Django have to run on two different ports

Comment: @Abdo Can you post the error that you get. It is difficult to know how to proceed without that info

Comment: He probably doesn't get an error, he's just redirected to a page server by React instead of getting the Django admin page. If you solved this, could you post the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Update your urls to admin/, It's worked for me.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/web', admin.site.urls),
path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
path('accounts/', include('account.urls')),
path('main-app/', include('main.urls')),
path('admin/password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),
     name='admin_password_reset'),
path('admin/password_reset/done/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
     name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
     name='password_reset_complete'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*',
                        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```